# How to get image form our galery use pickGalery function in ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework

i have a problem when i want to get image from my galery and display it to image 150x150. but when i already pick image in galery, the data is empt otherwise no image that i choose in

i use ionic v1 for my project

```
$scope.gallery = function ($event, id) {
            $rootScope.wizardData = $scope.wizardData;
            camera.pickGallery().then(function (dataUri) {
                console.log('bbb', dataUri)
                console.log('aaa', id)
                $state.go('app.merchantRegistrationStep4', { "identifier": id, "stateTarget": "app.merchantRegistrationStep4", "dataUrl": dataUri });
            });
        }
```

my question, is my $state.go is correct? thankyouu

Comment: I don't know it will work or not but Try: `$location.path()`

Comment: but, the problem is when i upload image, after cropp the iamge, i go to blank page.